# Is there a way to mock a Portal?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, struts2, liferay

I'm trying to set up unit testing. I'm using Struts2 and Liferay 6.1.

I'm getting the below error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getCompany(PortalUtil.java:305)
at com.mycomp.portlet.action.BasePortletAction.setupSiteAgent(BasePortletAction.java:1169)
```

This is because `PortalUtil.getPortal()` returns `null`. Is there a way I could somehow create a mock portal? There is no `MockPortal` class. I have found something called `MockPortalContext` but I'm not sure how to make use of it.

This is my code so far

`BaseTestCase.java`

```
public abstract class BaseTestCase extends TestCase {
private Dispatcher dispatcher;
protected ActionProxy proxy;
private static MockServletContext servletContext;
private MockHttpServletRequest request;
private MockHttpServletResponse response;

public BaseTestCase(String name) {
    super(name);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected <T>T createAction(Class<T> theClass, String namespace, String actionName, String methodName, HashMap<String, Object> actionContextMap, HashMap<String, Object> parameterMap) throws Exception {

    proxy = dispatcher.getContainer().getInstance(ActionProxyFactory.class).createActionProxy(namespace, actionName, methodName, new HashMap<String, Object>(), true, true);

    for (String key : actionContextMap.keySet()) {
        proxy.getInvocation().getInvocationContext().put(key, actionContextMap.get(key));
    }
    proxy.getInvocation().getInvocationContext().setParameters(parameterMap);
    proxy.setExecuteResult(true);

    ServletActionContext.setContext(proxy.getInvocation().getInvocationContext());
    request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
    ServletActionContext.setRequest(request);
    ServletActionContext.setResponse(response);
    ServletActionContext.setServletContext(servletContext);

    return (T) proxy.getAction();
}

protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    final String[] config = new String[]{"struts.xml", "mockApplicationContext.xml"};
    servletContext = new MockServletContext();
    final XmlWebApplicationContext appContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
    appContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
    appContext.setConfigLocations(config);
    appContext.refresh();
    servletContext.setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, appContext);

    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("actionPackages", "com.mycomp.portlet.action");
    dispatcher = new Dispatcher(servletContext, params);
    dispatcher.init();
    Dispatcher.setInstance(dispatcher);
}
}
```

`ActionTest.java`

```
public class ActionTest extends BaseTestCase {
private Map<String, Object> contextMap;
private Map<String, Object> parameterMap;
private MockPortletRequest portletRequest;
private final String REQUEST_LOCALE = "request_locale"; 

public ActionTest(String name) {
    super(name);
}

public void testShowDetail() throws Exception {
    init();
    parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameterMap.put(REQUEST_LOCALE, "en_GB");
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    PortletAction lspa = createAction(PortletAction.class, 
                                            "/view",
                                            "myAction",
                                            "myAction",
                                            (HashMap<String, Object>)contextMap,
                                            (HashMap<String, Object>)parameterMap);

    String result = proxy.execute();
    System.out.println(result);
}

private void init() {
    portletRequest = new MockPortletRequest();
    contextMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    contextMap.put(PortletActionConstants.REQUEST, portletRequest);
}

}
```

The [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/portlet/MockPortletRequest.html) says creating a `MockPortletRequst()` with the no-arg constructor creates it with a default `MockPortletContext` and `MockPortalContext` so I don't know why it's null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Powermock or jMockit to mock the static method call `PortalUtil.getPortal()`

Comment: I'm having some problems getting it to work. I created a new question for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500954/mocking-static-liferay-method

Answer (score 0):

Technically the answer has already been given by John B. I'd like to add a philosophical angle.

IMHO mocking a complex environment like a portal doesn't buy a lot, especially when we speak about *unit* testing. You'll gain more insight into your code by minimizing contact with *any* complex API and environment (not just a portal), rather decouple from that APIs.

One solution is to have very simple wiring in portlet classes (and code-review this) while extracting testable code into its own - fully tested - classes that don't call out to the external API, rather get their context passed in.

This would leave you with some very simple code that's not unit-tested, but in addition to the code-review you can (and should) add some integration/smoke tests that actually work in the full environment.

Sometimes a simple solution will be to quickly mock portal classes (or other external classes), but I don't see this as the preferred solution. As soon as you start writing significant setup code to prepare the environment, you've gained nothing when your test runs. And if it fails, you'll have to check it in the real environment anyways to see if your setup was accurate.

Sorry if this is bad news - IMHO it's inherent when you have any given API that has not been built with being replaceable in unit tests. And with my unwillingness to routinely have large setup routines in *unit* tests. I'd not call them unit tests, if this happens frequently - rather break down the (too complex) unit into more smaller ones. Or accept code-review for simple wiring (adaptation) code between two different APIs.

Comment: Thanks Olaf, that's really useful advice. I will take that on board. But unfortunately much of the code is already written and I will have to make it work as it is.