# Mocking static Liferay method

Tags: java, unit-testing, liferay, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to mock the `PortalUtil.getPortal()` method like so

```
PowerMock.mockStatic(PortalUtil.class);
Portal mockPortal = Mockito.mock(Portal.class);
Mockito.when(PortalUtil.getPortal()).thenReturn(mockPortal);
```

I'm getting the below error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
3. the parent of the mocked class is not public.
It is a limitation of the mock engine.
```

I know Mockito cannot mock static methods but I'm also using PowerMock which is supposed to make this possible. I also tried using `PowerMockito.mockStatic()` instead of `PowerMock.mockStatic()`

I have the below annotations at class level

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(PortalUtil.class)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think `@PrepareForTest` should take as an argument the name of the class you are testing (e.g. `MyBusinessLogicTest.class`), not the class you are trying to substitute (`PortalUtil.class`).

Comment: Still doesn't work. Thanks though

Comment: Portal mockPortal = Mockito.mock(Portal.class);
new PortalUtil().setPortal(mockPortal);
^ This worked

Comment: OK. Otherwise the `Mockito.when(PortalUtil.getPortal())` needed to use `PowerMock` not `Mockito`. Powermock can mock a static method call, Mockito cannot.

Comment: @steven35 So is your problem now solved? If so, please either provide an answer yourself or delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using this bit of code I stopped getting NPE

```
Portal mockPortal = Mockito.mock(Portal.class);
new PortalUtil().setPortal(mockPortal);
```